# dynamically created page in JQM can't fire pagecreated function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having some problems in my webpage.

I have a pageshow event in which I fire an ajax call to return some events from my server. After that, I  populate a list with them and create a page for all events with their data with this:

```
$("#modifyEvent").after('<div data-role="page" id="modifyEvent'+i+'"" data-theme="a">'+
bla bla bla...
);
```

Each event is well recognized and I can navigate to it and seeing all its data in the new page. But, I have a some buttons inside, each one with a class associated e.g: class="buttonDelete".

Also, I have a pagecreate  event in which I would wan to add all my functions related to that buttons:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", '#event', function() {
    $('.buttonDelete').click(function() {
```

I tried with classes and id but this function is never called. What is the correct way about calling function events in this case?

Comment: Are you creating the same page with same id several times?

Comment: Should I delete it? How can I do that? But, even in the first time I execute it, it already cannot fire that function.

Comment: It should be deleted before you add another one.

Comment: How can I delete multiples pages at the same time? I always add them with .after(...). Is there an order to delete all added this way? like set innerhtml to empty, empty or so?

Comment: Are you injecting more than one page dynamically? With different id for each?

Comment: Yes,I insert a lot of them. Maybe 20 or so each time. Each one with a diferent id, of course. I can navigate to them and back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64774/discussion-between-omar-and-biribu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are injecting the same page(s) without removing old one(s). The `pagecreate` does fire upon navigating to the dynamic page, however, your event listener(s) is attached to first element found in DOM.

```js
/* will fire on each page one time */
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#p1", function () {
   $(".button").on("click", clickHandler);
});
```

```html
<!-- dynamically inject pages - both in DOM -->
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
  <a class="button">Button</a> <!-- this one will always receive the binding -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="p1">
  <a class="button">Button</a> <!-- not this one -->
</div>
```

Your solution is to remove dynamically injected pages before creating new ones. The easiest way is to remove a page once hidden. Simply, add a custom class e.g. `dynamic` and remove any page with that class on `pagecontainerhide`.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function (e, data) {
   if ( data.prevPage.hasClass("dynamic") ) {
      data.prevPage.remove();
   }
});
```

`data.prevPage` is the page that is just hidden.

Update: `.hasClass("class")` is faster than `.is(".class")`.

Comment: You helped me a lot with this. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Biribu it's a pleasure to assist :)